# DC motor operation at no load

Tags: motor, dc-motor, electric-machine

I was solving a DC shunt motor question where no load is specified to:

- Speed=1000 rpm
- Rated armature current=3.33 A
- Rated voltage=230 V

And

- Ra=0.3
- Rsh=160
- Line current = 40 A (at full current)
  were also given.

And it was asked to find full load speed if arm. reac. reduces the flux by 4%.
The solution is as given below.[image]
Now, logically speaking, at no load, there is no current to armature winding and it should be disconnected? So there should be no current flowing through it, and so we should proceed in that manner but the logic in the given solution is different.
Where am I going wrong? And also I would appreciate if you could explain me the logic of the solution too.
Thanks